# Как привязать домен к vps на oracle free tier?

Tags: хостинг, dns, домен

Есть бесплатный инстанс на oracle, на котором развёрнут тестовый проект, который работает на 8080 http://140.238.221.163:8080. Была создана зона Networking - DNS Management - Zones - ugolock.tech в котором по умолчанию вот такие ns-ки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в панели регистратора домена добавил A запись с ip

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также добавил ns records

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот как я например добавил последнюю запись

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спустя сутки по адресу ugolock.tech:8080 ничего так и не появилось
Где я допустил ошибку и как её исправить?

Comment: `в панели регистратора домена добавил A запись с ip` — регистратор тут ни при чём. вот эти четыре ns-а: `$ dig ns ugolock.tech` должны знать о вашей a-записи, чтобы вернуть эту информацию по запросу к ним. // прозреваю, что для этого на второй картинке, которую вы нарисовали, вам надо было нажать кнопочку в левом верхнем углу. вы на ней такую красивую надпись изобразили: «add record». прямо загляденье.